# Using transitionend inside a mousemove event

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transitions, transition

My page has two divs (`#red` and `#blue`) and a mousemove event that is bound to the document object - this event cannot be changed by me. **(Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/bk8912fz/70/))**

When the cursor enters the red div, the blue div is pushed down by 50px. The mousemove handler does this by

1. adding attribute `data-moved` to the blue div (this attribute adds a transition effect for the top property of the blue div and signifies that the div has been moved)
2. setting the top position of the blue div to 50px.

This works as expected.

When the pointer exits the red div, the blue div is pushed back up to its original position using the same transition effect that was used to push it down. To do this, I first check if the blue div has been moved (i.e. if `restore.hasAttribute('data-moved')` is `true`). If it has been moved, I bind `transitionend` and `transitioncancel` events to it and then reset its top position to 0. The change in the value of the top position triggers the transition effect, which in turn triggers the transition event. Once the transition ends or is cancelled, the `transitionend` and `transitioncancel` event handlers remove the `data-moved` attribute before unbinding themselves from the blue div.

**This works fine 99.9% of the time but very rarely the transition event handlers fail to fire and the `data-moved` attribute is not removed from the blue div once it has been restored to its original position:**

[image]

This problem is very difficult to reproduce and seems to occur randomly when the cursor is made to very rapidly exit and re-enter the red div as shown below:

[image]

I really want be sure that I understand what's going on here. Since I can't reproduce the problem at will, I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting it.

The problem seems to be that the transition events don't fire when the cursor enters and exits the red div very quickly. My browser (Chome v87) is compatible with both transitionend and transitioncancel. The only other explanation I can think of is that when the cursor enters the red div, the top value's transition is queued. But if the cursor leaves red quickly enough, before the transition has had a chance to start, then the top value is unchanged when the mousemove handler queries it again and as a result, the transition events aren't fired. **Is this correct?**

According to W3:

> Transitions are a presentational effect. The computed value of a
> property transitions over time from the old value to the new value.
> Therefore if a script queries the computed style of a property as it
> is transitioning, it will see an intermediate value that represents
> the current animated value of the property.

Comment: In the meantime, I got rid of transitioncancel and tried using a debounce to create a small delay between the time that the cursor leaves the red div and the time that the blue div's top value is reset to 0. This delay gives the transition from 0 to 50px some time to start after the cursor enters the div so that there will always be a detectable change in the blue div's top value by the time the cursor exits the div, regardless of how fast it does so. [**Updated JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/03xegqvp/14/).

Comment: But I wonder if there is a simpler, more robust solution out there than `setTimeout` and I'm still unsure of what's going on in my post, so would greatly appreciate guidance from experienced developers.

Comment: I think I was overthinking this big time. I finally ended up with a really simple solution that just uses CSS classes, no timeouts or transition events. In the stylesheet, I define the style `.down, .up { transition: top 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.21, 1.08, 0.43, 0.97); }`. When the mouse enters the red div, the blue div gets assigned class `.up`, when it leaves the red div, the blue div gets assigned class `.down`. This way the transition effect is applied on the way down and on the way up. [**Updated JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/kLbmr8z7/20/).